# Как получить предыдущий и следующий элемент массива относительно, условно, 3?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой массив:

```
$array = ["red", "blue", "black", "green", "orange"];
```

Как можно:

1. получить следующий и предыдущий элемент относительно `$array[3]`?
2. сделать так, чтобы следующий элемент после `$array[4]` был "red"? и предыдущий `$array[0]` - был orange?

Конструкция такая:

```
$current = $array[3];
$next = ?;
$prev = ?;
```

Comment: смысл? $next=$array[4]; $prev=[2];

Answer (score 0):

№1

```
$current = $array[3];
$next = $array[3+1];
$prev = $array[3-1];
```

Через переменные тоже можно

```
$offset = 1;
$current = $array[3];
$next = $array[3+$offset];
$prev = $array[3-$offset];
```

№2

```
// Меняем местами нулевое и четвертое значения массива
list($array[0], $array[4]) = array($array[4], $array[0]);
```